# Stop a random string when the correct values are displayed

Tags: java

I have this code

```java
PFont f;
int displayWidth = 1280;
int displayHeight = 720;

int count;
int countAdvance;

void setup() {
  size(displayWidth, displayHeight);
  background(239,238,238);
  f = createFont("Heebo Black", 36, true);
  count = 1;
  countAdvance = 1;
}

void draw() {
 //I love you sentance
  String[] W1 = { 
    "I", "love", "you", "."
  };
  String[] W2 = { 
    "I", "love", "you", "."
  };
  String[] W3 = { 
    "I", "love", "you", "."
  };
  String[] W4 = { 
    "I", "love", "you", "."
  };

  int w1 = int(random(W1.length));
  int w2 = int(random(W2.length));
  int w3 = int(random(W3.length));
  int w4 = int(random(W4.length));

  String Sentence = W1[w1]+" "+W2[w2]+" "+W3[w3]+" "+W4[w4];
  println(Sentence);

  background(239,238,238);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textFont(f);
  fill(66,134,244);
  text(Sentence, 0.5*displayWidth, 0.5*displayHeight+25);

 //loop
  delay(1000);

}
```

and simply put, I want it to stop looping random values when the string writes out the correct sentence, in this case its "I love you.". What do I need to add in to make it stop so that W1[0] W2[1] etc.

Using Processing to write it if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work but I've never used Processing, so I'm not sure how correct your original code was.

```
void draw() {
  //I love you sentance
  String[] W1 = { 
    "I", "love", "you", "."
  };
  String[] W2 = { 
    "I", "love", "you", "."
  };
  String[] W3 = { 
    "I", "love", "you", "."
  };
  String[] W4 = { 
    "I", "love", "you", "."
  };
  String Sentence = "";
  while (!Sentence.equals("I love you .")) {//the last space is required
      int w1 = int(random(W1.length));
      int w2 = int(random(W2.length));
      int w3 = int(random(W3.length));
      int w4 = int(random(W4.length));

      Sentence = W1[w1]+" "+W2[w2]+" "+W3[w3]+" "+W4[w4];
      println(Sentence);

      background(239,238,238);
      textAlign(CENTER);
      textFont(f);
      fill(66,134,244);
      text(Sentence, 0.5*displayWidth, 0.5*displayHeight+25);

      delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is an endless loop: If there is a space between W3 and W4 it will never terminate, because there is no space between `you` and `.`

Comment: @michaeak Well that's the text he was looking for :D (but yeah, I'll fix it for posterity, I guess)

Comment: Haha right, didn't spot that, just looked at your post :)

Comment: Hmm that didn't seem to work, I run the code to a blank screen. Is there perhaps a long winded way that you can look up which part of the string array is being printed and if it matches the correct value stop its repeat?

Comment: @Koncept well I realized I made a basic logic error in the while loop, so try it with the !